# Gameplay video on android

Tags: android, video-capture

I don't know where exactly to ask this question:

How can i make gameplay video from android device ?
I need to capture video with normal FPS on android, is it possible ?
I now about AVD on PC but it's to slow (on my PC maybe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a bit late but... yeah, AVD is really slow with many computers. The main reason is that it doesn't use an x86 architecture, so everything has to be emulated.

But, if your game can run on Froyo, there is something you could do : try to use Android x86 projet within a VirtualBox (http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto). Usually it improves performances a lot. I don't know if it'll be enough to run a game properly, but you should definitively try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have mode for it, you only can make it from your computer directly.